# Prepend HTML text using DOMDocument without parent container

Tags: php, domdocument

Let's say I have `<p>Text</p>`

I'd like to create a function using DOMDocument to be able to insert text, eg:

```
insertText('<p>Text</p>', '<strong>1.</strong> ')
```

So that the result was `<p><strong>1.</strong> Text<p>`

I'm already accessing this paragraph tag, so I think I'm almost there, I just cannot figure out how to append plain text that can be read as HTML

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$question_paragraphs = array();
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$par = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
if ($par->length == 1) {
    $par->item(0)->setAttribute("class", "first last");
###
### How do I do this here?
###
}
```

Is it possible to inject text this way?

Comment: Is https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.insertbefore.php#117380 what you are after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get use the method `insertBefore` ([Official Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.insertbefore.php)) as follows

1. You create your `strong` element
2. You insert this node before the text node

```
$span = $dom->createElement('strong', '1.');
$par->item(0)->insertBefore($span, $par->item(0)->firstChild);
```

Please note that the second parameter of the `insertBefore` function is the child to which you want to prepend your tag. So in this case you can use `firstChild` as your `<p>` only contains the `Text`.

This will finally output

```
<p class="first last"><span>1.</span>Text</p>
```